# How to gather different expressions in the same group

Tags: regex

I want to detect lines which :

- Begin with "- "

OR

- Contains **=** or **<** or **>** and after the line have mandatory : **value** **(** **,** **)**

OR

- Contains **SN**

I try to detect which is as above. But my problem that it's detect two groups for lines :

```
BLOC3_ETAPE1=

U36_B1=
```

You find my test here : https://regex101.com/r/DFHmce/1

```
^(-.*|.*[<>=](?:(\s*)|(?:(?!\s*$).+[(](?:.*)[,](?:.*)[)](?:.*)))|(?:.*SN.*))$
```

**Expected Lines Result in the same group:**

```
TEST APPARTEMENT
S1=32.319156K(0.5M,37.5K)R 
S4<9.782835K(9.5K,10.5K)R 
S5>9.782835K(2.5K,10.5K)R 
U36_B1=
U6%=SN54LS02J
BLOC3_ETAPE1=
U9%=SN54LS273J  TestPos
```

Comment: Try `^(?:-.*|.*?SN.*|[^\r\n=<>]*[=<>].*(?=\r?\n[^,\r\n]*,))`  https://regex101.com/r/yHHr3Y/1

Comment: Why should the third `S5>9.782835K(2.5K,10.5K)R ` match? There is no comma on the next line, is does not contain SN and does not start with `-` right?

Comment: Because this line contain valeur after the operator > and there "(" and ")" in this line

Comment: So the mandatory values are `(` `,` or `)`

Comment: Yes and also the value before (

Comment: Would these be all the matches? https://regex101.com/r/4dSx4i/1

Comment: Yes all right but i want that it's not detect PS_OPEN and PS_OFF  because they have empty value before (

Comment: For example if there is line which : PS_TEST=14(,)    => This line will be detected because there is 14 between ( and operator

Comment: Then you could match at least a single non whitespace char after which is not any of the previously excluded chars https://regex101.com/r/XOAHU0/1

Comment: Yes, if you condition will be applied. The lines BLOC3_ETAPE1= and U36_B1= will not be detected. So i think the expression need to detect whitespace between ( and , and ) and the line  PS_TEST=14(,)  will be not detected because there is whitespace between ( and , and  between , and ) .  Sorry for the previous example

Comment: Or i need to add another condition to the expression for detect lines like : BLOC3_ETAPE1= and U36_B1= ?

Comment: Then you could add another alternation `^(?:-.*|.*?SN.*|[^\r\n=<>]*[=<>].*?\([^,\r\n]+,[^,\r\n]+\)|[^\r\n_]+_[^\r\n_]+=$).*` https://regex101.com/r/bWeXmn/1

Comment: Yes, this is right . Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an alternation with 4 parts.

```
^(?:-.*|.*?SN.*|[^\r\n=<>]*[=<>].*?\([^,\r\n]+,[^,\r\n]+\)|[^\r\n_]+_[^\r\n_]+=$).*
```

The 4 parts will match:

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group with 4 alternatives

  - `-.*` Match `-` and the rest of the line
  - `|` Or
  - `.*?SN.*` Match a line that contains SN
  - `|` Or
  - `[^\r\n=<>]*[=<>]` Match until any of `<` `=` or `>`
  - `.*?` Match any char except a newline as least as possible
  - `\([^,\r\n]+,[^,\r\n]+\)` Match `(` 1+ chars except a comma or newline. Match the `,` and again 1+ chars except a comma or newline and the closing `)`
  - `|` Or
  - `[^\r\n_]+_[^\r\n_]+=$` Match a part with an underscore ending on `=`
- `)` Close group
- `.*` Match the rest of the line

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bWeXmn/1)